# Absolute path of localhost coming after migrating to server in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website is http://clg2.givemyspace.com/

I have migrated from localhost to server but all the images are pointing to localhost. How can i fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do to fix that, the first comes to my mind is doing a [Search and Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) on your live site.

Search for: `http://localhost:7443/`

Replace with: `http://clg2.givemyspace.com/`

**Edit:**

Looks like the site is running on a subdir `/clg1/` on localhost, but the live is running on root dir. You will need to do two search/replace on the live site.

**First:**

Find: `http://localhost:7443/clg1/`

Replace with: `http://clg2.givemyspace.com/`

**Second:**

Find: `http://localhost:7443/`

Replace with: `http://clg2.givemyspace.com/`